Get the permissions of users with respect to the repositories via the API of ADO
How to get the permissions of users for the repositories via the API of Azure DevOps?

I can use the following PowerShell script to download the Permissions Report of the repos in the project.

Use the Repositories - List REST API to get the repo id (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) of each repo.
Use the Permissions Report - Create to create a permission report of the repo.
Use the Permissions Report - Get to check the status of the permission report.
When the permission report is reportStatus is completedSuccessfully, download the permission report with the Permissions Report Download - Download.

Sample PowerShell script :

# Replace the value with your actual values
$organizationUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/organizationname"
$personalAccessToken = ""
$projectName = "projectname"

# API endpoint for getting repositories
$reposUrl = "$organizationUrl/$projectName/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0"

# Create a session with PAT
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
}

try {
    # Get repositories
    $reposData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $reposUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error getting repositories: $_"
    exit
}

# List repositories
foreach ($repo in $reposData.value) {
    Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
    Write-Host $repo.name 

    $repoid =$repo.id
    $reponame =$repo.name

    # Define API URL
    $permissionsCreateApiUrl = "$organizationUrl/_apis/permissionsreport?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

    # Create permissions report
    $body = @{
        "descriptors" = @()  # List of groups and users to fetch permissions on. An empty list will fetch all groups and users in the organization.
        "reportName" = "Permission report $reponame"  # Name of the report to create, make it unique
        "resources" = @(
            @{
                "resourceId" = "$repoid"
                "resourceType" = "repo"
            }
        )
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    try {
        $permissionsCreateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $permissionsCreateApiUrl -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error creating permissions report: $_"
    }

    # Print report link
    $reportLink = $permissionsCreateResponse._Link.href 
    $reportLinkAPI="$($reportLink)?api-version=7.2-preview.1"

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    # Use Invoke-RestMethod to get the report status
    do {
        $ReportStatuResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $reportLinkAPI -Headers $headers -Method Get

        if ($ReportStatuResponse.reportStatus -ne "completedSuccessfully") {
            Write-Host "Report not completed yet, retrying in 10 seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        }
    } while ($ReportStatuResponse.reportStatus -ne "completedSuccessfully")

    $DownloadreportApi="$($reportLink)/download?api-version=7.2-preview.1"

    $filename ="Permission report for repository $reponame.json"

    #change the path to your path
    $PATH="C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\"+$filename  


    # Use Invoke-RestMethod to download the report
    try {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $DownloadreportApi -Headers $headers -Method Get -OutFile $PATH
        Write-Host "The $filename is downloaded"

    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error downloading report: $_"
    }
}


Test result: The permission reports are downloaded.

Note: During my test, I created too many reports in a short time pried, so at last my request was blocked due to Rate limits.

Thank you for the suggestion. I want to directly download the report even when the pipeline using the repo is active. Can you please suggest on how to handle such scenarios?

Hi @user10434309， I updated the answer with the full PowerShell script to download the permission report of the repo. Please check, Thanks!

Thank you once again it helped a lot. Now from this downloaded permission report I want to extract the teams and each member along with the permission. Can you kindly help me with this aswell?

Hi @user10434309, could you please clarify how you intend to extract permission information from the downloaded report? Are you considering converting the data format from JSON or conducting some form of data extraction analysis? It might be more effective to create a new question specifically for this issue to focus on the problem and get more suggestions.

Hi, I need to extract the team and user details, and the permissions configured for each repository from the downloaded report and generate a data table out of it.

can you please provide some suggestions on these.

The suggestion I can think of is to convert the json files into a csv table file through python programming. Could you please open a new question to focus on this data extraction issue? Writing code in comments is not easy to read. The question title can be something like "I have got the Permission report json file for Azure DevOps repo, how to generate a data table out of it". Please share the link to your new question with me and I'll be happy to help you.
